# Importing gradle project doesn't copy contents

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

Please mind that I'm new to Gradle and I don't completely understand how it works.

Usually when I import a java project in Eclipse it is copied in the current workspace. All subsequent modifications to source files are made inside of the workspace and NOT in the original project directory.

When I use the import "Gradle Project" wizard the imported project is not copied in the workspace directory. All modifications I make are outside of the workspace directory in the original gradle project.

I want to achieve the same results as in a normal java project. Can I copy the whole Gradle project directory into the workspace directory and import it from there ? Will something bad happen if I do this? I want this because usually I organize my work by workspaces and this gradle project outside of workspace is really bothering me.

Comment: when you import, did you check the box "Copy projects into workspace" ?

Comment: Gradle Import does not have such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, the workspace isn't the same as a workspace directory on your hard disk. You can add projects from different directories (not sharing a root workspace directory) into the Eclipse workspace - which means that changes to the source files affect the original files.

To answer your question: you can copy your projects to a workspace directory and then import them, but be aware that you will create a branch by copying your files (changes in your workspace wouldn't affect the original files).

Comment: I think my question was not clear enough. Since Gradle Import wizard does not have "Copy projects into workspace" I'm wondering if something bad will happen if I do it manually.

Comment: Copying the files manually and then importing them is exactly the same.

Comment: Should I copy the masterproject under workspace, like "c:\workspace\masterprject\gradleSubProjects" or I copy the gradle subprojects directly under workspace ("c:\workspace\GradleSubProjects") ?